# ARIA - iPhone VOICE OVER Chrome/Safari I want to set control to an element of DOM on page load

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

In a web page I'm showing search results over iPhone chrome browser with VOICE OVER ON. On page loading finished I want to move voice over control/focus to a special DOM element. Here javascript `focus()` with `tabindex` (either -1 or 0) does not work. Like inside document ready

```
$('#element').attr('tabindex',-1).focus();
```

Further currently on page load control stays with address bar and does not move to any other part. With swipe gestures only moves to controls of browser not to DOM elements.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @customcommander can you help and let me know the reason to down vote this question?

Comment: I didn’t downvote your question. I just fixed a typo. But you should perhaps include some code.

Comment: If it isn't moving to **any** DOM elements at all your problem lies elsewhere, do you have a stray `aria-hidden` or stray `tabindex`? Also (sorry if you know this I just wanted to check) are you familiar with how VoiceOver works (just for completeness due to you saying nothing can be accessed on the page do you know how to turn the nav wheel on etc.). If you can post a URL or a fiddle I will have a look in the morning for you.

Comment: I'm not well aware of VoiceOver work. Never used earlier. There is aria-hidden on other part of page (meun related)  but not on my desired one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your HTML, but I think the selector needs to be `.elements:first-child` or `.elements:first-of-type` instead of just `.elements:first`

Comment: selector is not the problem. tabindex attributed is added. control of VoiceOver does not move to this element on page load.